# Getting news feeds with JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, feed

I need to use an ajax call to get a news feed form google API and I have the following code:

```
function submitSearch(){
        var query = "business";
        var target = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=" + query + "&callback=processResults";

        $.ajax({
            url: target,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#resultSet').html(data);
            },
            error: alert(target)
        });
    }
```

For some reason using the URL directly in the browser works while using the AJAX call keeps resulting in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to
the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending 
a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option
is set to true.
```

ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

you need to set `dataType:"jsonp"` and remove the `&callback=processData` from the end of url

```
var query = "business";
var target = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q="+query;
$.ajax({
    url: target,
    cache: false,                   
    dataType:'jsonp',          
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.responseData.results[0].GsearchResultClass);

    },
    error: function(jxhr,e){
    alert(jxhr.status+" - "+e.responseText);        
    }
});
```

**here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6gCRF/8/**

Answer (score 0):

You can't make AJAX requests cross-domain. (Look up cross domain origin policy)

That said, there is a workaround to this: JSONP. It's essentially a hack, but it gets the job done. As for the JQuery specific implementation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make cross domain ajax requests  due to same-origin-policy or else you can use jsonp i.e json with padding.

same-origin-policy (SOP) is a browser security measure that restricts JavaScript code from talking with resources originating from other websites i.e resources loaded from any other domain and/or port. eg. JS running in a web page on http://google.com cannot interact with data loaded from http://cbs.com or even http://cbs.com:8081

Working around SOP

a) Proxy in your server: you create a end point in your app that talks to the external url and returns the result

b) Load the JSON response into a  tag otherwise jsonp i.e json with padding

there are some server side changes that go along with this.. read up on how to do it for your scripting language..

basically the response should be something like:

```
 jsonCallback({"Name": "Random", "Id" : 2432, "Rank": 453})
```